# Is there any way to cache build dependencies using AWS CodeBuild?

Tags: maven, amazon-web-services, gradle, aws-codebuild

Between 1 and 2 minutes of my AWS CodeBuilds are spent downloading dependencies from Maven Central.

Short of building a pre-provisioned Docker container, is there any way to cache these between builds?

Comment: I think creating a docker image is the intended way to do what you are looking for.  For most builds you really just need a Dockerfile that does basically what your "install" phase does and you're done.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

CodeBuild now [provides a cache feature](https://aws.amazon.com/blogs/devops/how-to-enable-caching-for-aws-codebuild/) you can use to pre-load your dependencies.

Answer (score 5):

Unsigned's answer is good but is a tad outdated. As of February 2019, CodeBuild allows both caching in an S3 bucket and allows the user to cache locally. You can now specify cache at 3 different layers of a build:

- Docker Layer Caching
- Git Layer Cahing (cache the last build and then only build from `git diff`)
- Custom caching - specified within the `cache:` portion of your buildspec.yml file. Personally, I cache my node_modules/ here and then cache at the Git Layer.

Source: https://aws.amazon.com/blogs/devops/improve-build-performance-and-save-time-using-local-caching-in-aws-codebuild/

Comment: Can you specify how to cache in S3 when the source is codepipeline and not GitHub